# Applying k-means on histopathological images using matlab

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I am applying k-means clustering algorithm on histopathological medical images to classify the pixels into classes. Everything is OK when applying k-means, but I have a tiny problem: When running k-means function (which is available in matlab) many times, image pixels appear in different colors each time. Can we make the colors of pixels the same when applying the k-means function many times?

Regrads,

Safaa

Comment: Are you explicitly calling `plot` as in the [example for `kmeans`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/kmeans.html)? Please note the use of `'r.'` and `'b.'` to set colors in that example.

Comment: Actually Iam concerned with the colors of the pixels when applying kmeans on the image itself, not the colors when plotting the data.I am applying the following function on the tissue image: [cluster_idx cluster_center] = kmeans(double_image,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean','Replicates',3);

Answer (score 0):

I had never used Matlab for this function. But I think Kmeans clustering results are based on the choice of its initial centre points. So perhaps, Matlab functions randomly choose K initial pixels, that possibly explains you got different results every time.

Answer (score 0):

k-means is a *randomized* algorithm. Every run will return a different result. But also with other clustering algorithms you will need to find a mapping of clusters to your intended meaning (e.g. colors).

You can cheat by either fixing the random generator or manually choosing initial means (I don't use Matlab, but I guess it does support that one way or another). Then the results will be more stable, but still not necessarily comparable across images.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab [kmeans](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/kmeans.html) function has a parameter named start, you can use it to define your starting seed.

> start ,  Method used to choose the initial cluster centroid positions, sometimes known as seeds.

As per documentation its default value is

> 'sample' Select k observations from X at random (default).

you have other options but only Matrix option is non-random. In this case you need to define a matrix
k-by-p matrix of centroid starting locations.

see below example taken from matlab documentation and modified here.

```
X = [randn(100,2)+ones(100,2);...
     randn(100,2)-ones(100,2)];
opts = statset('Display','final');

k = 2;
startPositions = [0.01 0.01 ; -0.01 -0.01];

[idx,ctrs] = kmeans(X,k,...
                    'Distance','city',...
                    'Options',opts,...
                    'Start',startPositions ...
                );

plot(X(idx==1,1),X(idx==1,2),'r.','MarkerSize',12)
hold on
plot(X(idx==2,1),X(idx==2,2),'b.','MarkerSize',12)
plot(ctrs(:,1),ctrs(:,2),'kx',...
     'MarkerSize',12,'LineWidth',2)
plot(ctrs(:,1),ctrs(:,2),'ko',...
     'MarkerSize',12,'LineWidth',2)
legend('Cluster 1','Cluster 2','Centroids',...
       'Location','NW')
```

Note that cluster centers appears to change since data itself is random. 
If you change data to static , cluster centers will be static too.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, but is this code applicable on images as described in my question?

Comment: This code is for 2d matrices. Your images are 2d matrices. It should be applicable.